# Shopware Store API Search ( INCLUDE | FILTER)

Tags: shopware6-api

I want to compress the Data of the Shopware Storefront Search API. At the Moment I get about 50.000 Lines of API

How can I compress the Data and just get the JSON Fields I need?

For my App I need only the Fields

- Product Number
- Product Name
- Product Price
- Product Description
- manufacturer Name
- URL

```
 $json->elements[$i]->productNumber;
 $json->elements[$i]->name;
 $json->elements[$i]->calculatedPrice->totalPrice;
 $json->elements[$i]->description;
 $json->elements[$i]->manufacturer->name;
 $json->elements[$i]->cover->media->thumbnails[3]->url;
 $json->elements[$i]->seoUrls[0]->seoPathInfo;
```

My API Call:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my-url.com/store-api/search?search=sofa&limit=4' \
--header 'sw-access-key: ***Shopware-Key***' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'sw-include-seo-urls: true' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: _GRECAPTCHA=1' \
```

I tryed to insert a API Body

like the Example Code but gets ignored.

```
--data '{
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 1,
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "field": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "field": "string",
      "order": "string",
      "naturalSorting": true
    }
  ],
  "post-filter": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "field": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ],
  "associations": {},
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "type": "string",
      "field": "string"
    }
  ],
  "grouping": [
    "string"
  ],
  "order": "string",
  "p": 1,
  "manufacturer": "string",
  "min-price": 0,
  "max-price": 0,
  "rating": 0,
  "shipping-free": false,
  "properties": "string",
  "manufacturer-filter": true,
  "price-filter": true,
  "rating-filter": true,
  "shipping-free-filter": true,
  "property-filter": true,
  "property-whitelist": "string",
  "reduce-aggregations": "string",
  "no-aggregations": "string",
  "only-aggregations": "string",
  "search": "string"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest using some kind of tool to compose your queries. Something like Postman will work. After you are done playing, you can export the working query from Postman to CURL as well.

I believe you are looking for the `includes` filter. [Here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria#includes-apialias) is a documentation URL for the full article.

I played around a little, but could not filter out sub-queries per your request. I bet it is possible, but you'll have to play around with it yourself as it will require some time :)

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'http://website.com/store-api/product' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'sw-access-key: XXXX' \
--data-raw '{
   "limit": 1,
   "includes": {
       "product": ["name", "productNumber", "calculatedPrice", "manufacturer", "cover", "description", "seoUrls"]
   },
   "associations": {
       "manufacturer": {},
       "seoUrls": {}
   }
}'
```